# Django All Columns Are Distinc

Tags: django, postgresql

Given that I have a data.

```
id, street, city created_at, verified

1, Main Street, Hull, 2/22/22, true

2, Other Street, Hull, 2/22/22, true

3, Bibble Way, Leicester, 2/22/22, true

4, Bibble Way, Leicester, 2/22/22, true

5, High Street, Londidium, 2/22/22, true

6, High Street, Londidium, 2/22/22, true
```

I want to distinct so that it would only delete `Bibble Way, Leicester` and `High Street, Londidium` because it is the only entry where all columns have a duplicate. I already tried `.distinct('street','city')` but it deletes if either street or city has a duplicate. I want to only delete if all columns match.

Whats the right query to get result of

```
id, street, city created_at, verified

1, Main Street, Hull, 2/22/22, true

2, Other Street, Hull, 2/22/22, true

3, Bibble Way, Leicester, 2/22/22, true

4, Bibble Way, Leicester, 2/22/22, true

5, High Street, Londidium, 2/22/22, true

6, High Street, Londidium, 2/22/22, true
```

values = ['street','city','created_at','verified']

I tried `.values('steet','city').distinct()`, and it deletes entries `Main Street, Hull` and `Other Street, Hull` and keeps one of them. Maybe because of `Hull`

What worked:

If this was a dataframe, the query that works for me is:      `mymodeldf.drop_duplicates(subset=values, keep='last')`

But **I want to do that in `distinct` so I dont have to make it a dataframe**

BTW. My class involved a datetime and boolean fields

Comment: what is your model name ?

Comment: try doing this `yourModel.objects.values('street','city').distinct()` replace `yourModel` by your real model name

Comment: I already tried that, and it deletes entries `Main Street, Hull` and `Other Street, Hull` and keeps one of them. If this was a dataframe, the query that works for me is:      `mymodeldf.drop_duplicates(subset=['city','street'], keep='last')`

But I want to do that in distinct so I dont have to make it a dataframe

Comment: try this first import this `from django.db.models import TextField` `from django.db.models.functions import Concat`

Comment: and execute this `yourModel.objects.annotate(distinct_street_city=Concat('street','city',output_field=TextField())).order_by('distinct_street_city').distinct('distinct_street_city')` this will only work if you are using postegre i assume you do.

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow what should I do if I have a list of fields I want to concateneate?  lets say I have `values = ['street','city']` then `yourModel.objects.annotate(distinct_street_city=Concat(*values, output_field=TextField())).order_by('distinct_street_city').distinct('distinct_street_city')`?

Comment: I get `raise FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. "` I also tried having the output as a charfield

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242557/discussion-between-thierno-amadou-sow-and-guraaaaashark).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do it in the DB? (Because, too many objects to load?)

Otherwise I would be tempted to do it in Python

```
last_address = '&&&&&&#£$%' # something impossible

for obj in Whatever.objects.all().order_by( 'city', 'street'):

    address = obj.city + obj.street
    if last_address == address : # a duplicate
        obj.delete()
    last_address = adddress
```

If you do want to do it in the DB you could annotate with the [Concat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) of street and city and then apply  `order_by` and `unique` to that annotation.